# Array of array and filtering performance

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy

What is the most efficient way to filter on an array of array?
Let's take this example:

```
[
   [key,timestamp,value],
   [2,12211212440,3.98],
   [2,12211212897,3.78],
   ...,
   [3,12211212440,3.28],
   [3,12211212897,3.58],
   ...,
   [4,12211212440,4.98],
   ... about 1 millions row :-)
]
```

So let's imagine we have more than 1 millions row. I want to filter by key and timestamp like key in array [3,7,9,...] and timestamp between time1 and time2.

Of course the first idea is to use database but for some reason I want to do it directly inside an application and not with a third party software.

Therefor I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to perform this filtering over a big amount of data. C++ list STL? Python Numpy? ...? But Numpy is base on C/C++, therefor I would imagine that the most efficient way is C/C++.

So could you give me some great idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Return rows that satisfy some condition (like `(2 < key < 5) AND (timestamp < 1234456)`) ? If the rows aren't already sorted somehow, then you need to iterate over each of them eitherway ... so there's not much choice here.

Comment: And what do you mean by array? You mention database, so are you free to choose the storage format?

Comment: @DanielJour Yes, I mean to apply some condition. Yes but there is so much way to do it. List STL, vector (I would imagine vector are faster to read data)... How to loop in the most efficient way? How to compare in the most efficient way? Which programming language would be the best? and so on...

Comment: @Thomas yes you are free to choose the storage format but actually I would suggest that the memory is the most efficient place to be faster...

Comment: It's not clear for me if your problem is reading filtererd input from the file into memory array, or if you intend to real all the file with the millions of line and filter in memory. In the latter case, it's not clear if by filtering you mean deleting unneeded items,  iterating over the items, or creating a new filtered array.  Please make an effort to clarify.

Comment: @Christophe the aims of my question is just about how to extract data of  a dataset in function of some condition. How to store/create/update the data, I don't mind. I am just interest about to get this data in the most efficient way. May be you would understand better if you look at numpy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really want to absolutely optimize the performance here, the answer is pretty much always to hand-code in C/C++.  But optimizing the run-time performance usually means a lot longer to write the code, so you need to figure out that tradeoff for yourself.

But you're right: numpy is indeed written in C, and most of its processing happens at that level.  As a result, the algorithms it implements are typically very close to the speed you could get by coding them yourself in C (or faster, because people have been working on numpy for a while).  So you probably shouldn't bother re-coding anything you can find in numpy.

Now the question is whether or not numpy has a *built-in* way of doing what you want.  Here's one way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
keys = np.array([2, 4])
t1 = 12211212440
t2 = 12211212897
d = np.array([[key,timestamp,value]
              for key in range(5)
              for timestamp in range(12211172430, 12211212997+1)
              for value in [3.98, 3.78, 3.28, 3.58, 4.98]])
filtered = d[(d[:, 1] >= t1) & (d[:, 1] <= t2)]  # Select rows in time span
filtered = filtered[np.in1d(filtered[:, 0], keys)]  # Select rows where key is in keys
```

It's not quite built-in, but two lines isn't bad.  Note that this `d` I made up has a little over a million entries.  On my laptop, this runs in around 4 milliseconds, which is around 4 nanoseconds per entry.  That's almost as fast as I would expect to be able to do it in C/C++.

Of course, there are other ways to do it.  Also, you might want to make a custom numpy `dtype` to handle the fact that you evidently have `int, int, float`, whereas numpy assumes `float, float, float`.  If I use a numpy `recarray` to do this, I get about a 50% speedup.  There's also `pandas`, which can handle that automatically, and has lots of selection functions.  In particular, translating the above straight to pandas runs in a little under 4 milliseconds -- maybe `pandas` is more clever about something:

```
import pandas as pd
keys = [2, 4]
t1 = 12211212440
t2 = 12211212897
d_pandas = pd.DataFrame([(key,timestamp,value)
                         for key in range(5)
                         for timestamp in range(12211172430, 12211212997+1)
                         for value in [3.98, 3.78, 3.28, 3.58, 4.98]],
                        columns=['key', 'timestamp', 'value'])
filtered = d_pandas[(d_pandas.timestamp >= t1) & (d_pandas.timestamp <= t2)]
filtered = filtered[filtered.timestamp.isin(keys)]
```

Of course, this isn't how I would code it in C++, so you could do better in principle.  In particular, I would expect to see a slowdown due to looping over the array two or three separate times; in C++ I would just do the loop once, check one condition, if that's true check the second condtion, if that's true keep that row.  If you're already using python, you could also look into `numba`, which lets you use python, but compiles it on the fly for you, so it's about as fast as C/C++.  Even a code as dumb as this runs very quickly:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

keys = np.array([2, 4], dtype='i8')
t1 = 12211212440
t2 = 12211212897
d_recarray = np.rec.array([(key,timestamp,value)
                           for key in range(5)
                           for timestamp in range(12211172430, 12211212997+1)
                           for value in [3.98, 3.78, 3.28, 3.58, 4.98]],
                          dtype=[('key', 'i8'), ('timestamp', 'i8'), ('value', 'f8')])

@nb.njit
def select_elements_recarrray(d_in, keys, t1, t2):
    d_out = np.empty_like(d_in)
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(d_in)):
        if d_in[i].timestamp >= t1 and d_in[i].timestamp <= t2:
            matched_key = False
            for j in range(len(keys)):
                if d_in[i].key == keys[j]:
                    matched_key = True
                    break
            if matched_key:
                d_out[k] = d_in[i]
                k += 1
    return d_out[:k]

filtered = select_elements_recarrray(d_recarray, keys, t1, t2)
```

The `jit` compilation takes a little time, though much less time than compiling a typical C code, and it also only has to happen once.  And then the filtering runs in just over one millisecond on my laptop -- almost four times faster than the numpy code, and about one nanosecond per input array element.  This is roughly as fast as I would expect to be able to do anything, even in C/C++.  So I don't expect it would be worth your time optimizing this.

I suggest you try something like this because it's so short and fast (and done for you).  Then, only if it's too slow, put in the work to do something better.  I don't know what you're doing, but chances are this will not make up a large fraction of the time your code takes to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's exactly the kind of response I was looking for. I hope to get some more of them from some others ;-)

Comment: On Monday, I will give some try with C++ and Python. At the moment we don't have chosen a programming language, all will depends on how easily we can solve our problem. Actually I am more comfortable in C/C++ but I heard a lot about this Numpy library in Python. So let's see...

Answer (score 1):

Quick'n'dirty filtering with C, single threaded, relying only on the operating system for buffering and the like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

double const fromTime = 3.45f;
double const toTime = 11.5f;
unsigned const someKeys[] = {21, 42, 63, 84};

bool matchingKey(unsigned const key) {
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(someKeys) / sizeof(someKeys[0]); ++i) {
    if (someKeys[i] == key) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

bool matchingTime(double const time) {
  return (time >= fromTime) && (time < toTime);
}

int main() {
  char buffer[100];
  time_t start_time = time(NULL);
  clock_t start_clock = clock();
  while (fgets(buffer, 100, stdin) != NULL) {
    size_t const lineLength = strlen(buffer);
    assert(lineLength > 0);
    if (buffer[lineLength - 1] != '\n') {
      fprintf(stderr, "Line too long:\n%s\nBye!\n", buffer);
      return 1;
    }
    unsigned key;
    double timestamp;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%u %lf", &key, &timestamp) != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse line:\n%sBye!\n", buffer);
    }
    if (matchingTime(timestamp) && matchingKey(key)) {
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
  }
  time_t end_time = time(NULL);
  clock_t end_clock = clock();
  fprintf(stderr, "time: %lf clock: %lf\n",
      difftime(end_time, start_time),
      (double) (end_clock - start_clock) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  if (!feof(stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something bad happend, bye!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There's *a lot* one could optimize here, but let's look how it runs:

```
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 generate.c -o generate
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 filter.c -o filter
$ ./generate | time ./filter > /dev/null 
time: 67.000000 clock: 66.535009
66.08user 0.45system 1:07.16elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 596maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+178minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

This is the result of filtering 100 million random rows. I ran this on a laptop with an [Intel P6100](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Pentium-P6100-Notebook-Processor.37083.0.html), so nothing high end.

This is about 670 nanoseconds per row. Note that you cannot compare this to Mike's results since on the one hand this (of course) depends on the available performance from the system (mainly CPU) and my test includes time taken by the operating system (Linux x86-64) to forward the data via the pipes as well as parsing the data and printing it again.

For reference here's `generate`'s code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned randomKey(void) {
  return rand() % 128;
}

double randomTime(void) {
  double a = rand(), b = rand();
  return (a > b) ? (a / b) : (b / a);
}


int main() {
  unsigned long const rows = 100000000UL;
  srand(time(NULL));
  unsigned long r;
  for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
    printf("%u %lf\n", randomKey(), randomTime());
  }
  return 0;
}
```